# nginx proxy - fetch a url and sent it to /dev/null

Tags: caching, nginx

I'm trying to get nginx to fetch an image at a given URL and discard the contents.    The reason I'm doing this is by fetching the image,  I'll pull it into cache and speed up later requests.

Any advice how to do this?

Comment: Is the url pointing to the server nginx is running on or another server? Do you control the domain the url is pointing to or not?

Comment: yeah,  i control all parts of the system.

Comment: Are both on the same server or not?

Comment: not currently,  but i can move things around if needed.  got a good idea?

Comment: Just trying to tease some information about your setup since you have provided none at all ... in the hope that either I or someone else might be able to venture an answer to your query!

Comment: they aren't on the same server but that can be changed if there's a solution that needs them to be.